# How Functional Programming addresses concurrent increment/decrement operations invoked by different users?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, clojure, functional-programming

Using Functional language, How can 2 different parties achieve the result of increment/decrement operations concurrently?

For the below scenario, Let's say, I've 2 quantities in stock and 2 users in e-commerce site block 1 quantity each concurrently. How can I mark the remaining stock as '0' in FP given the state is shared and immutable? I assume that each flow gets the copy of initial stock '2' and operates upon. If so, how will it reach '0' unless serialized?

***Kindly narrate this with some sample working code.***

How is this different from CAS operations on AtomicInteger (in JAVA) where the client is expected to retry on failure? (Both in terms of approach and efficiency)